# Access Form checkbox to update date in another table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm trying to make a form checkbox update a date in another table.

```
Private Sub Delivered_AfterUpdate()
If Delivered = -1 Then
    [tool implentation].[date] = Now()
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error on the `[tool implentation].[date] = Now()` line.

I would like if any time the checkbox is clicked (check and un-check) the date is updated.

Comment: *How* is is "not working"? Are you getting any errors? Please read [mcve], and [edit] your post accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: That said I believe table updates need to involve some kind of `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the "[tool implentation].[date] = Now()" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your table is also the form's recordset here. If it is not you will need something to determine which record in the table you want to edit.

```
Private Sub Delivered_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Delivered = True Then  
        With Me.Recordset
             .Edit
             ![ImplementationDate] = Now()
             .Update
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

You can leave `Me.Delivered = -1` if you want but I find True/False to be easier to read.

I also recommend not naming something Date, I'm not sure if it actually matters as a column name, but it is both a builtin function and data type. So I changed it.

You should also indent your code, it will be a nightmare as you get more lines.

Comment: I got an error at .Edit when i click on the checkbox.

Comment: Is the table the recordset of the form?

Comment: Yes the table is the recordset of the form.

Comment: Run-time error '3021'.  I'm getting the error when I check the box on a box that has not been checked.  If I uncheck a box I do not get an error.

Comment: Runtime error 3021 means there is no current record. What is the record number at the bottom of the form? You aren't getting the error when you uncheck it because there is an if statement and it only runs when checked to true.

Comment: Are you using DAO or ADO?

Comment: I do not know what DAO or ADO mean.

Comment: DAO is the default data table in Access. It stands for Data Access Objects. ADO is a more universal data table and stands for ActiveX Data Objects. If you don't know then it's probably DAO, and shouldn't be an issue here.